# 2 GroupBy em uma consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, group-by

Em Mysql tenho uma tabela de login com o campo **dia** e **ID do usuário**:

```
28-01-2019 - a
28-01-2019 - a
29-01-2019 - a
29-01-2019 - b
29-01-2019 - b
30-01-2019 - a
30-01-2019 - b
30-01-2019 - c
```

O que eu preciso é dar dois Group By e ter a seguinte soma:

- Quantos usuários se logaram por dia (ex: no caso do dia 28 seria 1 e no dia 30 seriam 3)

É possível com uma única consulta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neste caso você deve usar a cláusula `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT t.dia,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.usuario) AS quantidade
  FROM tabela t
 GROUP BY t.dia
 ORDER BY t.dia
```

---

> [`GROUP BY Modifiers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
>
> The `GROUP BY` clause permits a `WITH ROLLUP` modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. `ROLLUP` thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. For example, `ROLLUP` can be used to provide support for `OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)` operations.
>
> Suppose that a sales table has year, country, product, and profit columns for recording sales profitability:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> To summarize table contents per year, use a simple `GROUP BY` like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula `GROUP BY` permite um modificador`WITH ROLLUP` que faz com que a saída de resumo inclua linhas extras que representam operações de resumo de nível superior (isto é, super agregadas). O `ROLLUP` permite-lhe responder a questões em múltiplos níveis de análise com uma única consulta. Por exemplo, `ROLLUP` pode ser usado para fornecer suporte para operações`OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)`.
>
> Suponha que uma tabela de vendas tenha colunas de ano, país, produto e lucro para registrar a lucratividade das vendas:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> Para resumir o conteúdo da tabela por ano, use um `GROUP BY` simples assim:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

---

Você pode conferir a execução no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37e673/2).