# Count somente em dados não repitidos

Tags: mysql

Considere as tabelas fictícias a seguir:

```
Venda = id_venda, data, id_carrinho

Carinho = id_carrinho

ItemCarrinho = id_item, id_carrinho, id_produto
```

Suponhamos que existe 1 registro em venda, 1 registro em carrinho e 2 registros em `itemCarrinho`.

Se eu fizer esse `select` abaixo:

```
select count(b.id_carrinho) as qtd from Venda as a, Carrinho as b, 
ItemCarrinho as c where a.id_venda = 1 and b.id_carrinho = 
a.id_carrinho and c.id_carrinho = b.id_carrinho
```

ele me retorna contado em qtd o valor 2, sendo que o correto seria 1. 
Como consertar isso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [2 GroupBy em uma consulta Mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358934/2-groupby-em-uma-consulta-mysql)

Comment: Talvez você possa deixar de lado a junção com a tabela  ItemCarrinho mas, se a lógica de sua aplicação não permite, você também pode utilizar: COUNT(DISTINCT b.id_carrinho).